# database does not storing the content between angular brackets "<>"

Tags: java, mysql

I am using this java code to insert a txt file (which contain a java program) into MySQL database:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String fileName = "copyEvens.txt";

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            File file = new File(fileName);
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into code_table(language, code, passkey, program_name) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            pstmt.setString(1, "java");
            pstmt.setAsciiStream(2, fis, (int) file.length());
            pstmt.setString(3, "ved");
            pstmt.setString(4, "copyEvens");

            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            pstmt.close();
            fis.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

the txt file contain this program :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class copyEvens 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str  =in.nextLine();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        String []token = str.split(" ");
        int array[] = new int[token.length];
        for(int i=0; i<token.length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(token[i]);
        }
        copyEvens obj = new copyEvens();
        int result[] = obj.copyEvens(array, n);
        for(int i: result)
        {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        } 
        System.out.println();
    }

    public int[] copyEvens(int[] nums, int count) 
    {        
        int l = 0;
        int temp[] = new int[count];
          for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
          {
              if(nums[i]%2 == 0)
              {
                  temp[l] = nums[i];
                  if(l!=(count-1))
                    l++;
                  else
                    break;
              }
          }
          return temp;
    }
}
```

but in the database it is not storing the full program as it is mentioned just above. It is storing only this much program like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class copyEvens 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str  =in.nextLine();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        String []token = str.split(" ");
        int array[] = new int[token.length];
        **for(int i=0; i**
```

After analyzing this I found that the program does not storing the things between this  "<" ">" angular brackets. As, after this "`for(int i=0; i`" it should be "`for(int i=0; i<token.length; i++)`" and more..

Kindly help on this why it is not storing the content between angular brackets "<>".

Comment: Could you explain the difference here?  "for(int i=0; i" it should be "for(int i=0; i

Comment: There are a few character that breaks different languages and databases you need to decode them and encode them ... http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: How exactly have you determined that the portion of the file following the "<" character is not stored in the database? I suspect that the value IS stored, and that the issue is in later displaying this, and the "<" character is being interpreted by the web browser as a tag. But that's just a guess. Before we chase down the rabbit hole of "it's not stored in the database", let's verify what is actually being stored.

Comment: yeah, you are right, it is storing the all the things in the db but while printing it is omitting the things written between this "<>"  brackets.  so How i overcome to this error?? Should i try to read the all code and if we found the angular (<>) brackets then add "/" before it ??

Comment: I am still not able to print the code between "<>". Please suggest what and how i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to dump the code directly into the database.  If it is inserted as you expect (which there is absolutely no reason it shouldn't) then you will need to escape your data before inserting it.  PHP has a htmlspecialchars function that does this for you but you will need to find an equivalent library that does this for Java - I had a quick scan online and found some messy code that does this but it was far too shoddy for me to recommend. to anyone :).